# How to validate appveyor.yml using command in terminal?

Tags: appveyor

I want to forbid to commit invalid `appveyor.yml` in my git repo. In order to do that I need some tool that can be called from terminal to validate my `appveyor.yml`(something like `circleci config validate` for CircleCI). But I found that validation possible only from my Appveyor account page. Is there some app for validation `appveyor.yml` that can be called from terminal?
Or maybe someone know how to write proper curl request that open my Appveyor account and validate my `appveyor.yml` in backgound?

I tried to find reference to such tool in Appveyor' docs but with no luck.